# Does this model in R make sense?

Tags: r, anova

I have repeated measures model but the nested factor is a random factor. Now, every example of repeated measures anova with the aov function I came across has a fixed factor. Their model looks like :

```r
aov(values~ A +Error(Subject/A),long)
```

Using the logic behind the Error term, I figured if my factor A is random, I should include A in the Error term, like this :

```r
aov(values~ Error(A + (Subject/A)),long)
```

This seems to work and doesn't produce any error in R, but I have never seen anyone write it this way before ? Does it make sense ?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks !